# Mule ESB How to exit a transaction gracefully

Tags: transactions, mule, mule-studio

I'm using Mule Studio and my flow has a transaction in it. If a file is not found, i'd like to exit the transaction without throwing an error. Mule Exception stack-traces are huge and ugly in logs.

Is there a way to just die <transaction-end> or something?

At this point I'd consider some form of  tag to stop processing the message all  together.

code to messy to give example but here's an excerpt:

```
<transactional action="ALWAYS_BEGIN" doc:name="Transactional">
    <flow-ref name="ingest_provider" doc:name="Ingest Provider"/>
    <flow-ref name="create_asset" doc:name="Create Asset"/>
    <foreach collection="#[payload['Asset Resource']]" doc:name="Foreach Asset Resource">
        <or-filter doc:name="Only movie or preview"> 
            <expression-filter expression="#[payload['resource_class']=='movie']"/>  
            <expression-filter expression="#[payload['resource_class']=='preview']"/>  
        </or-filter>
        <expression-transformer expression="payload.put('resource_guid', payload.guid); payload" doc:name="Expression"/>

        <choice doc:name="Choice">
            <when expression="#[!fileExists(new File('${ipvod.ingest.in.av}', payload.Content[0].filename).toString())]">                           
                <logger message="Could not locate resource_file=#[new File('${ipvod.ingest.in.av}', payload.Content[0].filename).toString()] for asset_guid=#[flowVars.asset_guid]" level="ERROR" doc:name="Logger"/>
                <set-payload value="#[asset_guid]" doc:name="Set Payload"/>

<!-- I'd like the code to die here -->
                <scripting:component doc:name="Script">
                    <scripting:script engine="Groovy"><![CDATA[
                                throw new Exception('File Not Found!')
                    ]]></scripting:script>
                </scripting:component>
            </when>
        </choice>
```

Comment: What resources are enrolled in this `transactional` block? It `ALWAYS_BEGIN`s a transaction but I don't see any inbound nor outbound endpoint so I don't really see what's its usage...

Comment: Also you have a for each so do you want to break out of it or simply skip the execution of the rest of the flow for the current message?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to go with Mule Exception Strategy if you want to exit gracefully.

Here is a link of Mule's Exception Strategy Use Cases which has got some examples.

http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation-3.2/display/32X/Exception+Strategy+Most+Common+Use+Cases

Hope this helps.